# How to move the left and right margins in from 0

Tags: html, lightbox

I'm trying to use this "lightbox" code was the W3School:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

And while it works ok what I want to do is have the left and right margins be like 100px and I can't figure out how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

RON

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for?

```
.row{
    margin: 0 100px;
}
```

Comment: I tried add .row {margins: 0 10px; } (not 100) but that just made the four image stacked 2 and 2. Ideally I would like the four images (mine are 400px wide) go to the width of the screen with a margin on each side.